# Python append a class to a list

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program to parse and load files I have in my media collection. This program would be given a directory and would begin to recursively scan and place all media files(currently just TV shows) in a list. The Issue I am currently running into is it reads all the file names and locations in correctly. But when it goes to store the information in a the list the information for seasons and episodes are wrong. The Season information is somewhat correct in that it displays the correct number of seasons but the season numbers are wrong. The episodes are completely wrong. It does read everything in correctly when only one show is read in to the list.

At the bottom I narrow my problem down and try to make it more simple.

For example when I only read in one show this is what I get when I print out the list.

```
    0) Stargate Atlantis
    -1) Exit
    What show do you want to look at?
    0
    0) Season 2
    1) Season 4
    2) Season 1
    3) Season 3
    4) Season 5
    -1) Exit
    What season do you want to look at?
    2
    0) Stargate Atlantis - S05e16 - Brain Storm.mkv
    1) Stargate Atlantis - S05e17 - Infection.mkv
    2) Stargate Atlantis - S05e18 - Identity.mkv
    3) Stargate Atlantis - S05e19 - Vegas.mkv
    4) Stargate Atlantis - S05e20 - Enemy At The Gate.mkv
    5) Stargate Atlantis - S05e01 - Search And Rescue.mkv
    6) Stargate Atlantis - S05e02 - The Seed.mkv
    7) Stargate Atlantis - S05e03 - Broken Ties.mkv
    8) Stargate Atlantis - S05e04 - The Daedalus Variations.mkv
    9) Stargate Atlantis - S05e05 - Ghost In The Machine.mkv
    10) Stargate Atlantis - S05e06 - The Shrine.mkv
    11) Stargate Atlantis - S05e07 - Whispers.mkv
    12) Stargate Atlantis - S05e08 - The Queen.mkv
    13) Stargate Atlantis - S05e09 - Tracker.mkv
    14) Stargate Atlantis - S05e10 - First Contact.mkv
    15) Stargate Atlantis - S05e11 - The Lost Tribe.mkv
    16) Stargate Atlantis - S05e12 - Outsiders.mkv
    17) Stargate Atlantis - S05e13 - Inquisition.mkv
    18) Stargate Atlantis - S05e14 - The Prodigal.mkv
    19) Stargate Atlantis - S05e15 - Remnants.mkv
    -1) Exit
    What episode do you want to look at?
```

Everything is good except the fact os.walk reads them in semi-randomly. But when I read in more then one TV show it begins to mess things up. Here is what happens when I read in two TV shows.

```
0) Stargate Atlantis
1) Brooklyn Nine-Nine
-1) Exit
What show do you want to look at?
0 # I selected option 0 (Stargate Atlantis)
0) Season 1
1) Season 2
2) Season 1
3) Season 3
4) Season 5
-1) Exit
What season do you want to look at?
0
0) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S02E02 - Chocolate Milk.mp4
1) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S02E01 - Undercover.mp4
2) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S02E04 - Halloween II.mp4
3) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S02E03 - The Jimmy Jab Games.mp4
4) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E01 - Pilot.mkv
5) Brooklyn Nine Nine - S01E02 - HDTV x264 LOL.mp4
6) Brooklyn Nine Nine - S01E04 - HDTV x264 LOL.mp4
7) Brooklyn Nine Nine - S01E07 - 480p HDTV x264mSD.mkv
8) Brooklyn Nine Nine - S01E08 - 480p HDTV x264mSD.mkv
9) Brooklyn Nine Nine - S01E09 - 480p HDTV x264mSD.1.2.mkv
10) Brooklyn Nine Nine - S01E10 - 480p HDTV x264mSD.1.mkv
11) Brooklyn Nine Nine - S01E11 - 480p HDTV x264mSD.1.2.mkv
12) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E18 - HDTV x264 KILLERS.mp4
13) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E13 - HDTV x264 EXCELLENCE.mp4
14) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E14 - HDTV x264 EXCELLENCE.mp4
15) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E15 - HDTV x2642HD.mp4
16) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E16 - REAL HDTV x264 EXCELLENCE.mp4
17) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E17 - PROPER HDTV x264KILLERS.mp4
18) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E19 - HDTV x2642HD.mp4
19) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E20 - PROPER HDTV x2642HD.mp4
20) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E21 - HDTV x264EXCELLENCE.mp4
21) Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S01E22 - HDTV x264EXCELLENCE.mp4
22) NULL
23) NULL
24) NULL
25) NULL
26) NULL
27) NULL
28) NULL
29) NULL
30) NULL
31) NULL
32) NULL
33) NULL
34) NULL
35) NULL
36) NULL
37) NULL
38) NULL
39) NULL
40) NULL
41) NULL
42) NULL
-1) Exit
What episode do you want to look at?
```

Once I add in more TV shows things get worse and if I try to view the first season it will usually go up to option 433 and with 90% of them being NULL.

Here is my code now

```
__author__ = "michael"
import socket, thread, os, time, tvdb_api

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9876
connections = 0


class media ():
    tv = []
    index = {}
    budget = 0
    numoftvshows = 0
    exit = 0
    # add existing will not add any files that contain these extensions
    ignore_list = [".html", ".url", ".txt", ".db", ".srt", ".jpg", ".png", ".docx", ".doc", ".rar", ".zip", ".tar", ".7z", ".dat", ".bmp", ".gif", ".psd", ".tga", ".tif", ".pdf", ".xlr", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".jar", ".exe", ".sav", ".rom", ".php", ".part", ".crdownload", ".msi", ".torrent", ".idx", ".sub", ".nfo"]


class Tvshows():
    name = 'NULL'
    seasons = []
    curseason = 0
    numofseasons = 0
    nextep = 0
    showstat = 0
    rootdir = 'NULL'


class Seas():
    exist = 0
    complete = 0
    episodes = []
    numofeps = 0
    realnum = 1


class epi():
    releasedate = []
    status = 0
    filename = 'NULL'
    realnum = 0


def initiliazer(mdata):
    # setting counter variables to 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    # checks to see if data file is empty
    # if data file is empty skips loading and goes to menu
    if os.stat("tvdata.dat").st_size == 0:
        print "tvdata.dat is empty skipping load"
        return mdata
    else:
        # opens files and uses '|' as a delimeter
        print "Loading data please wait...."
        file = open("tvdata.dat", "rw")
        for line in file:
            fields = line.split('|')
            # appends a new show everytime a new one is found
            mdata.tv.append(Tvshows())
            mdata.numoftvshows += 1
            mdata.tv[j].name = fields[i]
            mdata.index[mdata.tv[j].name] = j
            i += 1
            mdata.tv[j].curseason = int(fields[i])
            i += 1
            mdata.tv[j].numofseasons = int(fields[i])
            i += 1
            mdata.tv[j].nextep = int(fields[i])
            i += 1
            mdata.tv[j].showstat = int(fields[i])
            i += 1
            mdata.tv[j].rootdir = fields[i]
            i += 1
            n = 0
            while n < mdata.tv[j].numofseasons:
                # appends a new season every time a new one is added
                mdata.tv[j].seasons.append(Seas())
                mdata.tv[j].seasons[n].realnum = int(fields[i])
                i += 1
                mdata.tv[j].seasons[n].numofeps = int(fields[i])
                i += 1
                k = 0
                while k < mdata.tv[j].seasons[n].numofeps:
                    # appends a new episode every time a new one is added
                    mdata.tv[j].seasons[n].episodes.append(epi())
                    mdata.tv[j].seasons[n].episodes[k].filename = fields[i]
                    i += 1
                    mdata.tv[j].seasons[n].episodes[k].status = int(fields[i])
                    i += 1
                    k += 1
                n += 1
            j += 1
    print "Loading data complete"
    file.close()
    return mdata


def printdata(mdata, client):
    i = 0
    while i < mdata.numoftvshows:
        client.send(str(i))
        client.send(") ")
        client.send(mdata.tv[i].name)
        client.send("\n")
        i += 1
    client.send("-1) Exit\n")
    client.send("What show do you want to look at?\n")
    showpick = client.recv(4096)
    showpick = showpick.rstrip()
    if showpick == "-1":
        return
    showpick = int(showpick)

    i = 0
    while i < mdata.tv[showpick].numofseasons:
        client.send(str(i))
        client.send(") Season ")
        client.send(str(mdata.tv[showpick].seasons[i].realnum))
        client.send("\n")
        i += 1
    client.send("-1) Exit\n")
    client.send("What season do you want to look at?\n")
    seaspick = client.recv(4096)
    seaspick = seaspick.rstrip()
    if seaspick == "-1":
        return
    seaspick = int(seaspick)

    i = 0
    while i < mdata.tv[showpick].seasons[seaspick].numofeps - 1:
        client.send(str(i))
        client.send(") ")
        client.send(mdata.tv[showpick].seasons[seaspick].episodes[i].filename)
        client.send("\n")
        i += 1
    client.send("-1) Exit\n")
    client.send("What episode do you want to look at?\n")
    epipick = client.recv(4096)
    epipick = epipick.rstrip()
    if epipick == -1:
        return
    return
    epipick = int(epipick)


def addexistshow(mdata, client):
    nameofshow = ">>NULL<<"  # added the >><< to make sure this never matches a show name
    seascheck = "Season #"  # makes sure this is not found by default
    client.send("What directory are your files located in?\n")
    workdir = client.recv(4096)
    workdir = workdir.rstrip()
    errnum = 0
    k = -1
    for cur, dir, filenames in os.walk(workdir):
        rootdir = cur
        if nameofshow not in cur and cur != workdir and cur[0] != '.':
            strlen = len(workdir)
            cur = cur[strlen:]
            if cur[0] == '/':
                cur = cur[1:]
            mdata.tv.append(Tvshows())
            mdata.numoftvshows += 1
            k += 1
            mdata.tv[k].name = cur
            nameofshow = cur
            mdata.tv[k].rootdir = rootdir
            i = -1
            seascheck = "Season #"
            client.send(cur)
            client.send("\n")
        elif seascheck not in cur and cur != workdir:
            strlen = len(workdir + '/' + nameofshow + '/')
            cur = cur[strlen:]
            if cur != seascheck and "season" in cur.lower():
                i += 1
                mdata.tv[k].seasons.append(Seas())
                mdata.tv[k].numofseasons += 1
                mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].exist = 1
                mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].realnum = int(cur[7:])
                seascheck = cur
            if "season" in cur.lower():
                mdata.tv[mdata.numoftvshows - 1].seasons[i].realnum = int(seascheck[7:])
                mdata.tv[mdata.numoftvshows - 1].seasons[i].numofeps += 1
                mdata.tv[mdata.numoftvshows - 1].seasons[i].exist = 1
            client.send(cur)
            client.send("\n")
        if seascheck in cur:
            j = 0
            for line in filenames:
                good = True
                for ext in mdata.ignore_list:
                    if ext in line[-6:]:
                        good = False
                        client.send("[*] Skipping ")
                        client.send(ext)
                        client.send(" found in ")
                        client.send(line)
                        client.send("\n")
                if good is True:
                    try:
                        #print "tv =", k, "season =", i, "episode =", j
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes.append(epi())
                        epname = line.split(",")
                        realnumbuff = epname[0].split(" - ")
                        realnumbuff = int(realnumbuff[1][4:])
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].realnum = realnumbuff
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].filename = epname[0]
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].status = 1
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].numofeps += 1
                        client.send(mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].filename)
                        client.send("\n")
                        if mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].filename == "Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S02E03 - The Jimmy Jab Games.mp4":
                            return mdata
                        j += 1
                    except Exception as e:
                        client.send("[!] Error as ")
                        client.send(str(e))
                        client.send("\n")
                        errnum += 1
    #print mdata.tv[9].name
    #print mdata.tv[25].seasons[3].episodes[190].filename
    if errnum > 0:
        client.send("\n[!] WARNING - A total of ")
        client.send(errnum)
        client.send(" errors were encountered! This could cause problems proceed with caution.\n")
    return mdata


def writedatafile( mdata):
    file = open("tvdata.da", "w")
    for i in xrange(0, mdata.numoftvshows):
        file.write(mdata.tv[i].name)
        file.write("|")
        file.write(str(mdata.tv[i].curseason))
        file.write("|")
        file.write(str(mdata.tv[i].numofseasons))
        file.write("|")
        file.write(str(mdata.tv[i].nextep))
        file.write("|")
        file.write(str(mdata.tv[i].showstat))
        file.write("|")
        file.write(mdata.tv[i].rootdir)
        for j in xrange(0, mdata.tv[i].numofseasons):
            file.write(str(mdata.tv[i].seasons[j].realnum))
            file.write("|")
            file.write(str(mdata.tv[i].seasons[j].numofeps))
            file.write("|")
            for k in xrange(0, mdata.tv[i].seasons[j].numofeps):
                file.write(mdata.tv[i].seasons[j].episodes[k].filename)
                file.write("|")
                file.write(str(mdata.tv[i].seasons[j].episodes[k].status))
                file.write("|")
    return mdata


def addnewshow(mdata):
    show = raw_input("What show do you want to add?\n")



def menu( mdata, client):
    client.send('----Media Get----\n\n')
    client.send(' 1) Add a new show    2) Add an existing show\n')
    client.send(' 3) Print Database    4) Rewrite data file\n')
    client.send('-1) Exit Menu        -2) Exit program completely\n')
    pick = client.recv(4096)
    pick = pick.rstrip()
    if pick == "1":
        addnewshow(mdata)
    elif pick == "2":
        addexistshow(mdata, client)
    elif pick == "3":
        printdata(mdata, client)
    elif pick == "4":
        writedatafile(mdata)
    elif pick == "-1":
        mdata.exit = 1
    elif pick == "-2":
        mdata.exit = 1
    return mdata


def t_handle(client, address, s, mdata):
    while mdata.exit != 1:
        mdata = menu(mdata, client)
    client.send("[*] closing connection\n")
    client.close
    time.sleep(2)
    thread.exit()


def main():
    mdata = media()
    mdata = initiliazer(mdata)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(1)
    connections = -1
    while 1:
        connections += 1
        print "Number of clients connected", connections
        client, address = s.accept()
        thread.start_new_thread(t_handle,(client,address, s, mdata))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

--- Narrowed code---

I believe the issues are in my class declarations and where I read in my show data from files. When I view the code with a debugger all the seasons are located at the same memory addresses across all shows. I think this is because I am appending a class to a list wrong but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    class media ():
    tv = []
    index = {}
    budget = 0
    numoftvshows = 0
    exit = 0
    # add existing will not add any files that contain these extensions
    ignore_list = [".html", ".url", ".txt", ".db", ".srt", ".jpg", ".png", ".docx", ".doc", ".rar", ".zip", ".tar", ".7z", ".dat", ".bmp", ".gif", ".psd", ".tga", ".tif", ".pdf", ".xlr", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".jar", ".exe", ".sav", ".rom", ".php", ".part", ".crdownload", ".msi", ".torrent", ".idx", ".sub", ".nfo"]


class Tvshows():
    name = 'NULL'
    seasons = []
    curseason = 0
    numofseasons = 0
    nextep = 0
    showstat = 0
    rootdir = 'NULL'


class Seas():
    exist = 0
    complete = 0
    episodes = []
    numofeps = 0
    realnum = 1


class epi():
    releasedate = []
    status = 0
    filename = 'NULL'
    realnum = 0


def addexistshow(mdata, client):
    nameofshow = ">>NULL<<"  # added the >><< to make sure this never matches a show name
    seascheck = "Season #"  # makes sure this is not found by default
    client.send("What directory are your files located in?\n")
    workdir = client.recv(4096)
    workdir = workdir.rstrip()
    errnum = 0
    k = -1
    for cur, dir, filenames in os.walk(workdir):
        rootdir = cur
        if nameofshow not in cur and cur != workdir and cur[0] != '.':
            strlen = len(workdir)
            cur = cur[strlen:]
            if cur[0] == '/':
                cur = cur[1:]
            mdata.tv.append(Tvshows())
            mdata.numoftvshows += 1
            k += 1
            mdata.tv[k].name = cur
            nameofshow = cur
            mdata.tv[k].rootdir = rootdir
            i = -1
            seascheck = "Season #"
            client.send(cur)
            client.send("\n")
        elif seascheck not in cur and cur != workdir:
            strlen = len(workdir + '/' + nameofshow + '/')
            cur = cur[strlen:]
            if cur != seascheck and "season" in cur.lower():
                i += 1
                mdata.tv[k].seasons.append(Seas())
                mdata.tv[k].numofseasons += 1
                mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].exist = 1
                mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].realnum = int(cur[7:])
                seascheck = cur
            if "season" in cur.lower():
                mdata.tv[mdata.numoftvshows - 1].seasons[i].realnum = int(seascheck[7:])
                mdata.tv[mdata.numoftvshows - 1].seasons[i].numofeps += 1
                mdata.tv[mdata.numoftvshows - 1].seasons[i].exist = 1
            client.send(cur)
            client.send("\n")
        if seascheck in cur:
            j = 0
            for line in filenames:
                good = True
                for ext in mdata.ignore_list:
                    if ext in line[-6:]:
                        good = False
                        client.send("[*] Skipping ")
                        client.send(ext)
                        client.send(" found in ")
                        client.send(line)
                        client.send("\n")
                if good is True:
                    try:
                        #print "tv =", k, "season =", i, "episode =", j
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes.append(epi())
                        epname = line.split(",")
                        realnumbuff = epname[0].split(" - ")
                        realnumbuff = int(realnumbuff[1][4:])
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].realnum = realnumbuff
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].filename = epname[0]
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].status = 1
                        mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].numofeps += 1
                        client.send(mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].filename)
                        client.send("\n")
                        if mdata.tv[k].seasons[i].episodes[j].filename == "Brooklyn Nine-Nine - S02E03 - The Jimmy Jab Games.mp4":
                            return mdata
                        j += 1
                    except Exception as e:
                        client.send("[!] Error as ")
                        client.send(str(e))
                        client.send("\n")
                        errnum += 1
    #print mdata.tv[9].name
    #print mdata.tv[25].seasons[3].episodes[190].filename
    if errnum > 0:
        client.send("\n[!] WARNING - A total of ")
        client.send(errnum)
        client.send(" errors were encountered! This could cause problems proceed with caution.\n")
    return mdata
```

The point of this project is to automate legally buying new TV shows when they come out for a class project. I believe I am doing something wrong with my classes and this is causing my to overwrite the same season list over and over again instead of each show and season getting its own unique list.

I would really appreciate any help you can give me and if any more info is needed let me know and I will add what I can.

Comment: That's a lot of code to wade through, especially since *we* probably don't have the right files to try it on - have you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I narrowed down the problem to two areas of the code and added them in a code sample at end of my post.

Comment: @MichaelCarson Why are you declaring classes like this: `class Seas()`? You should use `class Seas(object)`. Or if you are using Python 3 you are able to use `class Seas`. I cannot see why you would want empty parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way to initialize members of a class:

```
class Tvshows():
    name = 'NULL'
    seasons = []
    curseason = 0
    ...
```

These members will be properties of the class itself rather than individual instances. This will cause problems with mutable values: when you later call `some_instance.seasons.append(x)`, it will be appended to the list shared by all instances.

You should instead initialize all members in the `__init__` method, which will be called on each instance separately:

```
class Tvshows():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'NULL'
        self.seasons = []
        self.curseason = 0
        ...
```